# The set of coefficients of cubics having three real roots is connected

Tags: connectedness, roots-of-cubics

Let $D$ be the set of all $3-tuples$, $(a,b,c)$ in $R^3$ such that the cubic polynomial $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ has three real roots, i.e., $D=\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^3+ax^2+bx+c \textit{ factors into linear factors over } \mathbb{R} \}$. Then show that $D$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard topology.

I have no clue whatsoever for this problem. Can someone suggest me how to approach this problem? I found some NASC conditions for a cubic to have three real roots but I think there might be some elegant way to solve this.

If we can show that $D$ is path connected then we are through. Another approach might be expressing this set as a continuous image of some known connected set. I am unable to proceed using only these ideas.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): "**Avoid "no clue" questions.**
Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community, which represents a significant waste of time - including for yourself ..."

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$ then the coefficients $a,b,c$ of $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$ depend continuously on $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.  But the triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ can be deformed to $(-1,0,1)$ continuously while preserving the order in the triple of distinct roots.  Therefore the set is connected.